# Как запустить несколько сайтов на одном ip?

Tags: python, html

я пользуюсь хостингом Debian, сайты написаны на flask

Answer (score 3):

нужен dns

либо - Для такого, обычно, заводят несколько доменов, которые указывают на 1 ip, а на этом ip разворачивают nginx, который по запрашиваемому домену будет перенаправлять запросы к нужным сайтам.